# How to select the same values from different excel files with their all row values?

Tags: r

I have two Excel files.

I will match the first column of File A and the first column of File B.

If the values of the first column in File A is in the first column of File B, I want to get those values along their all row values.

File A:

```
"MD"
697
5637
23132-87
42-MG-BA
647-V
769-P
8305C
8505C
ABC-1
ACHN
AGS
ALL-PO
ALL-SIL
```

File B:

```
"AZD5153" "IC50"
697 0,155445
5637    11,767517
22RV1   2,144765
23132-87    1,882177
42-MG-BA    2,252297
639-V   6,412568
647-V   12,435838
769-P   1,770539
786-0   15,7086
8305C   5,638946
8505C   1,387637
8-MG-BA 2,207205
```

Expected File:

```
"MD"  "IC50"
697 0,155445
5637    11,767517
23132-87    1,882177
42-MG-BA    2,252297
647-V   12,435838
769-P   1,770539
8305C   5,638946
8505C   1,387637
```

Comment: `FileB %>% filter(AZD5153 %in% FileA$MD) %>% select(MD = AZD5153)` should work.

Comment: You may want to look into merging the two data sets.  One resource to help you learn this is here:  https://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html#inner-join

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of problems with the two columns. The `MD` column is not an exact match of `AZD5153`. In some cases, you want a partial match while in some, there may be an exact match. A join solution may not work.

I would suggest a "record linkage" approach. Read up on the documentation of `reclin` package. Here's a basic workflow:

- Generate pairs for each of the column → Compare pairs → Score Pairs and link your data.

A general code solution would look like this:

```r
library(reclin)
# Make sure that the values are string for both the data frames. 
pair_blocking(df1, df2, blocking_var = "MD") %>% 
    compare_pairs(by = "name", default_comparator = lcs())
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion but I have gotten an Error in this step

pair_blocking(df1, df2, blocking_var = "MD") %>%
+     compare_pairs(by = "name", default_comparator = lcs())

Error in `[.data.frame`(y, blocking_var) : undefined columns selected

Comment: That's because you need to make sure that both the files in R are data frames.